# UIButton not being hidden in iphone app

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am trying to hide UIButton but it is not being hidden. In the same code I am successfully hiding a UILabel. What is the error in my code ?

```
if ([typeOne isEqualToString:@"DDWC"]) {

    questionButtonTwo.hidden=YES;
    questionButtonTwoTwo.hidden=YES;
    questionButtonTwoThree.hidden=YES;
    questionButtonTwoFour.hidden=YES;
    questionButtonTwoFive.hidden=YES;
    questionButtonTwoSix.hidden=YES;
    questionButtonTwoSeven.hidden=YES;
    questionButtonTwoEight.hidden=YES;
    checkLableTwo.hidden=NO;
    checkLableTwoTwo.hidden=NO;
    checkLableTwoThree.hidden=NO;

    checkLableTwoFour.hidden=NO;

    checkLableTwoFive.hidden=NO;
    checkLableTwoSix.hidden=NO;
    checkLableTwoSeven.hidden=NO;
    checkLableTwoEight.hidden=NO;

    }
```

Comment: Check if the if condition is ever been true

Comment: yes it is true other why lable code works over here

Comment: you are saying you are hiding your label but your code is label.hidden=NO;

Comment: yes i have changed it now i tested hidden=YES it works fine

Comment: If you have used the xib to create these buttons then u will have to connect them first ....

Comment: its obvious to connect them i have tried this also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you define an IBOutlet for that button and connect it to the actual button in Interface Builder? If not, try it.

Comment: yes i have tried it but i don't know why it is doing like this

Comment: Maybe the mistake is somewhere else. Add a breakpoint just before hiding the button and check if it's nil.